# How to use use IP in RESTful API request

Tags: rest, restful-url

I want to send request like this:

```
GET https://220.181.57.217/v1/groups
Host: test.restapi.foobar.com
```

But got this error:

> error: SSLError: hostname '220.181.57.217' doesn't match 'test.restapi.foobar.com' while doing GET request to URL: https://220.181.57.217/v1/groups

According to [rfc2616: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), it is due to how host is determined:

> 1. If Request-URI is an absoluteURI, the host is part of the
>    Request-URI. Any Host header field value in the request MUST be
>    ignored.
> 2. If the Request-URI is not an absoluteURI, and the request includes
>    a Host header field, the host is determined by the Host header
>    field value.

The reason for using IP in request URI is: in China, mobile dns resolution is not so good. Connect API server with IP is much better.

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using cURL to communicate with the `API` you could try to turn off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`

Comment: Thanks, @DarkBee. But that is not an option. I want to keep data transmissions secure.

Comment: Then afaik you will need to use the proper hostname because thats the one they've set in the SSL certificate

Answer (score 0):

check your GET URL,whether it has any ports number after IP,whther it is http or https protocol and your REST API path.

Comment: No ports after IP, and the protocol is httpS. I'm sure because the API service is developed by my teammate :)